# Positioning Image in top of first column

Tags: beamer, diagrams, presentations

I am making a presentation in which I need the image at top of left column but it is aligned at the center. What can do to move it to top?

```
 \begin{columns}{\onlytextwidth}

\column{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{figure}

  \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Table.PNG}
  
\end{figure}

\column{0.7\textwidth}

\begin{enumerate}[i]

    \item  Number of students who are enrolled in Mathematics only.

    \item Number of students who are enrolled in Physics only.

    \item Number of students who are enrolled in Chemistry only.

    \item Number of students who are enrolled in exactly one subject.

\item  Number of students who are enrolled in at least one subject.

\item Number of students who are not enrolled in any subject.

\end{enumerate}

\end{columns}
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you delete the `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` directives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the `T` option as shown in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]
  \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.7\textwidth}
    \begin{enumerate}[i]
      \item  Number of students who are enrolled in Mathematics only.
      \item Number of students who are enrolled in Physics only.
      \item Number of students who are enrolled in Chemistry only.
      \item Number of students who are enrolled in exactly one subject.
      \item  Number of students who are enrolled in at least one subject.
      \item Number of students who are not enrolled in any subject.
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{column}
\end{columns} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```